# Releasing Scala Object resources

Tags: scala, object

How can I release memory resources held by a Scala object?  I presume the internals of an Object work much like a Java static class inside the jvm?  Is there a way to release these resources, say via using a classloader or other technique?

Comment: I have to ask, why? Why are you at the point of asking this and what problem are you addressing such that this has to be the way you need to solve it?

Comment: Internals of an `object` in Scala are much like Java's thread safe singleton. Normally, you shouldn't even bother releasing resources - garbage collector does the work for you

Comment: The 'why' is this:  I want to write an executive; a container for a self contained sandbox of classes and objects, which will allocate resources.  From time to time I need to refresh the sandboxe managed by the executive...essentially flushing all resources held by the sandbox and possibly loading different classes and objects, all managed by the executive.  I cant have droppings from old objects lying around.

Comment: Think of it like a mini cloud.  The executive my nit even be aware/visible to what is in the sandbox...its just holding it, but it also needs to be able to flust it!

Answer (score 1):

If you control the code, try to avoid needing to do this. Objects should be assumed to be lazily-created, non-destroyable globals. As such, they really shouldn't hold large or mutable state if it can at all be avoided.

Comment: (i realize this isn't exactly an answer, and would personally be interested in seeing one, but would still recommend avoiding the pattern.)

Answer (score 0):

Given your comments, I believe the most reasonable way is to make the executive own the sandbox (i.e. nobody but the executive has direct references to the sandbox) and just create and initialize a new sandbox instead of "refreshing" an existing one. The old sandbox will be garbage-collected and anything it loaded should be as well.

Comment: That's exactly what I'd like.  Problem is if anyone puts objects into the sandbox code even though all the classes are easily cleaned up, the objects, and any memory they've allocated, stick around, making for a hideous memory leak.  Haven't found a way around this yet.

Comment: How are your sandboxes implemented? E.g. does each run in its own JVM? There is nothing special about objects from JVM's point of view, so if everything else gets cleaned up, they should be as well.

Comment: That's my last resort.  I'm hoping to run in the same jvm.  I thought having different classloaders would do this but now I'm not sure...just because I throw away a classloader (say for a sandbox) I'm not sure that also cleans up static objects loaded by that classloader.